# Preview callback

Tags: camera, commonsware-cwac

I found it's way easier to use CWAC-CAMERA to show a preview. So I want to use CWAC-CAMERA with Zxing Core to decode QRCode.

Is there a way to implement : Preview.Callback to obtain byte[] data of Preview ? So I can use Zxing core to decode.

Thanks

Comment: CWAC-Camera is no longer supported, and it never supported what you want. Use the camera APIs directly.